# Remember count between tabs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in a mobile application. Users are able to add products to an order. But I am using different tabs so that the user can switch between categories and for each category the products get shown who belong to that category. These products can be added to his/her order. If a user clicks on the '+' the product gets added and de '+' changes into a 1. If the user clicks again the 1 changes in a 2 etc... This works great BUT when the user clicks another tab to view products of another category and after that comes back to the previous tab the amounts of all products are back to '+' but should be 1 or 2 or 3 or ... if the the user already added this product to his order.

**Example**

[image]
[image]
[image]

So after adding some products of category 'Frappes' the user changes to category Ice tea and after returning to 'Frappes' the products that he added before should still be marked but this isn't the case as you can see...

**AngularJS**

```
//COMPOSE ORDER ADD/REMOVE/UPDATE 
    $scope.productRemove = function($event, pid){
        $scope.productid = pid;
        if($scope.order.length > 0)
        {
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++){
               if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
               {
                   if($scope.order[b].aantal > 1)
                   {
                      $scope.order[b].aantal--;
                      document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML - 1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $scope.order.splice(b,1);
                       document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = '+';
                       //update quantity in app UI!
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.productAdd = function($event,pname, pid, pprice) {
        $scope.pzelfdeid = -1;
        $scope.pzelfde = -1;
        $scope.prodname = pname;
        $scope.prodid = pid;
        $scope.price = pprice;
        if($scope.order.length == 0){
            $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
            $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;
        }        
        else if($scope.order.length > 0){
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
                {
                    $scope.pzelfdeid = $scope.order[b].prodid;   
                    $scope.pzelfde = b;
                }
            }
            if($scope.pzelfde > -1)
            {
                $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal++;
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal;             
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;               
            }
        }

    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="lattes.html">
      <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <ons-carousel-item>  
          <ons-list>  
            <ons-list-item ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy: 'category'">
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="#" id="aantal" ng-click="productAdd($event,product.name, product.id, product.price)">+</a></li>
                 <li>
                    <ons-col width="100%">
                        <div class="name">
                          {{product.name}}
                        </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        {{product.description}}
                        </div>
                    </ons-col>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#" id="aantal"  ng-click="productRemove($event, product.id)">-</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </ons-list-item>
          </ons-list>
      </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
    </ons-template>
```

So any idea's to solve this properly?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: all right will remember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data that is "stored" on a controller is only valid as long as the controller instance is valid. When you change the tab / view a new instance of the controller will be created, hence the current selection is lost.

You can use Angular services to hold information that is persisted during the user session. Or to put in the other way around, services will only be instantiated once per application, hence a value stored in a service will not be lost on view change.

A good start is to read on [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

In your example you'd create a service that abstracts the logic for treating products => addProduct and removeProduct:

```
angular.module(...).factory('Products', function() {

  var products = [];

  return {
    add: function() {
      // ...
    }

    remove: function() {
      // ...
    }

    getAll: function() { return products; }
  };
})
```

You are then able to inject the service into the controller and access its methods:

```
.controller('SomeController', function(Products) {

  $scope.products = Products.getAll();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [serrvices](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for application wide variables. These are singleton objects that you can treat as application models. When controllers are passed a service as a parameter they receive a reference to an object, which they can use to manipulate state. e.g.

```
angular.module('main', [])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myService) { 
    $scope.data = myService;
})

.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, myService) { 
    $scope.data = myService;
    $scope.changedata = function() { 
        $scope.data.variable = 456; // will update myService's variable to 456 when called
    }
})

.factory('myService', function() {return { variable: 123 }; });
```

Sopme HTML code to change service variable via `ng-click` and see the effects:

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">{{data.variable}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2" ng-click="changedata()">{{data.variable}}</div>    
</div>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q10hx4ey/).